Esp32/Arduino receive UDP data from server
I have a esp32 that has a LTE module connected to it. So it can use mobile data (4G) to communicate with my REST-API server.
But I want the connection to be bi-directional, so it can send and receive data.
But if the esp32 doesn't have an IP Address (a public), how can I send data from my server to my esp32?

It’s better to explain more about your issue. Generally, there are two ways to handle this:

Open the connection (socket) from the ESP32, and do not close that link, so the data can be transmitted through the socket.
Define an endpoint in your API. On the ESP, you can check it periodically.


I chose a MQTT server, because most IOT devices uses it and it is light weight. Basicly WebSocket for IOT
